# resources for learning more about pedestrian tracking

Tags: computer-vision, visual-tracking

I would like to build a computer vision application capable of doing robust pedestrian tracking in potentially crowded environments from a single video source. To this end I would like to find resources in order to learn as much about the current state of the art as possible. This could be:

- recent survey papers
- papers outlining novel approaches that have been demonstrated with success
- open-source applications or algorithms
- online courses or even course materials such as slide decks comparing different approaches
- ...

Is there anything along these lines that you could point me to? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have so far:

- A Survey of Human-Sensing: Methods for Detecting Presence, Count, Location, Track, and Identity; Teixeira, Dublon and Savvides
- I just found the question [People Detection and Tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16673698/people-detection-and-tracking) on SO which also has some good leads.